# Button text alignment issue in Mac

Tags: css, button, alignment

I have a "a" tag button in my project which looks perfect on windows but on Mac it's text alignment is not correct (please check the screenshots). In Mac I've checked on FireFox and Safari, it's not aligned.. However, on Windows, it's perfect.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhbF6.png)

Here's the HTML:

```
<a class="primary-button" href="#">SHOP NOW</a>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.primary-button {
@extend .greenbg,
.white,
.text-center,
.normal,
.font-12,
.border-radius-25;
border: solid 1px transparent;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0px 18px;
line-height: 26px; }
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Is this CSS or SCSS or SASS?

Comment: It's SCSS......

Comment: Fyi the "a" tag is called an anchor.